# How to access an API protected by Oauth2 from iguana using lua

Tags: oauth-2.0, lua, iguana-ui

I am trying to access an API endpoint that was protected by Oauth2, from the iguana(6.1.4) using Lua programming language. I don't have any previous experience with lua programming. I tried to use packages for that but couldn't able to use packages inside iguana.

it would be great if someone can post the code snippets of lua client code to invoke the OAuth 2 secured API endpoints